# How does this trick for estimating bit error rate break down?

Tags: measurement-error, bernoulli-process

Imagine you are receiving a message over and over via a lossy data path.  The path causes bit errors but does not affect the length of the message (or shift any bits).  You don't know the *actual* message but you will get many copies of it so you can reconstruct it (e.g. with a median filter).  You want to estimate the error rate of the channel by observing the sequence of messages.

I solved this problem a while ago by "learning" the expected message and counting errors as $\text{population}(\text{learned} \oplus \text{current})$.  Today it struck me that the learning component may be unnecessary:  For low error rates you could approximate the rate as $\frac{\text{population}(\text{previous} \oplus \text{current})}{2}$.  That is effectively measuring the previous frame against the current *and vice versa* simultaneously.  At low error rates half of the errors can be expected to be due to $\text{previous}$ and half due to $\text{current}$.

My assumption about the independence of the errors in $\text{previous}$ and $\text{current}$ breaks down as the error rate increases and repeated errors become more likely.  How does the actual error rate impact the rate given by my estimation?

Comment: Can you explain the definition of your notation please? It sounds like you're discussing something a little related to a well-known result but your notation is unfamiliar to me (and I expect to most people here), so I can't be sure what you're actually saying.

Comment: Messages are sequences of bits.  The XOR operation $\oplus$ is `1` where bits differ and `0` where they are the same.  The population of a set of bits is the count of `1` bits.

Comment: Thanks; useful. Actually, I knew what a XOR was, I just didn't know that's what the $\oplus$ symbol was in this case (it has a variety of possible meanings). What does the operator "$\text{population}(.)$ do?

Comment: The population of a set of bits is the count of 1 bits.  Also "popcnt" and the bitwise Hamming weight.  Lots of applications in Chess AI programming have explored population count algorithms.

Comment: Oh, okay. I now understand that you had already answered that, but I didn't understand the explanation before because the word *population* means something *utterly* different to us here, and I misunderstood what you were even saying the first time (that is, this: 'The population of a set of bits is the count of `1` bits' didn't mean to me what you hoped it did. I got it now.)

Comment: Is the 'error rate' the underlying (and here's where we'd say the word 'population' instead of underlying) proportion of bits that have errors (are different to what they should be)?

Comment: Next: what, precisely, does 'learning' the expected message consist of? Is that simply what you were describing in the previous sentence or something different to that?

Comment: @Glen_b: "Learning" by observing many messages and assuming that the median value of each bit (of all the bits at the same position in the set of messages) was the actual value.  This was then used as the basis for each comparison against a newly arriving message.

Comment: Ben, I see you have included the 'autocorrelation' tag. If there's autocorrelation in the bit-flipping, the independence assumption I made is wrong. I don't know that it will necessarily change the answer (I'd need to make a different assumption that should work), but I want to be clear I understand. Is there autocorrelation in the bit-flips?

Comment: @Glen_b: I'm probably using "autocorrelation" too informally.  I only meant it in terms of "comparing a signal with itself".  It's hard to tag questions on stackexchange sites outside your expertise.  Feel free to retag as appropriate (in fact, in the past the re-tagging of my questions has essentially answered them by identifying the field I needed to read about).

Comment: Thanks. In this case you're not comparing the signal with itself shifted in time, but with another (noisy) copy at the same times. I'll remove the tag as it's likely to bring in a lot of people getting hits on searches for problems of a very different kind. I've also added the bernoulli-process tag, since that describes the assumed occurences of bit-flips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I now follow enough to understand that your alternative estimate is wrong, because if the two messages are independent (in the probability sense), then the expected number of observed differences in two messages *won't* be twice the expected difference between the learned message and the current one.

It won't even be twice the expected difference between the *actual* message and the current one.

That's because *both* the current and previous message can flip the same bit. You have to subtract that off the sum.

If we assume that the probability that a bit gets flipped is always $p$ (here $p$ is a population - in the statistical sense - parameter) and all flips are mutually independent, then the expected probability two corresponding bits differ between two messages is

\begin{eqnarray}
P(\text{two messages disagree on a given bit}) &=& 1-P(\text{two messages agree there}) \\
&=& 1- P(\text{both unflipped or both flipped})  \\
&=& 1-[(1-p)^2 + p^2] \\
&=& 1-[1 - 2p +2p^2]\\
&=& 2p-2p^2
\end{eqnarray}

So you have to solve a quadratic:  $2p^2 - 2p +q = 0$

which implies that $p = \frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{q}{2}}$.

Your question implies the error rate is low. If you know it's below 0.5, you take the smaller answer:

$p = \frac{1}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{q}{2}}$

[image: bit error / message difference relationship]

That in turn suggests the MLE

$\hat p = \frac{1}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\hat q}{2}}$

Let me see if I can translate that into your terms:

$\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\text{population}(\text{previous} \oplus \text{current})}{2\text{size}(\text{current})}}$

is the estimate of the per bit error rate. You'd then multiply the whole expression by $\text{size}(\text{current})$ to estimate $\text{population}(\text{actual} \oplus \text{current})$.

Incidentally, it should be possible to put standard errors on/give confidence intervals for the various estimates of quantities if you need them. (As $q$ gets anywhere twoard 0.5, the uncertainty in $p$ grows rapidly.)

Comment: Your first three paragraphs accurately reflect the flaw I perceive and tried to describe in my question.  The remainder of your answer takes the form I'd expect (higher $p$ makes the estimate worse) but I'll have to study it to understand what you're saying.

Comment: I believe your translation is exactly what I was looking for!  Better, even, because I assumed that higher $p$ would describe an increasingly poor error bound for the estimate.  I didn't expect it could "feed back" and be used to correct the estimate.

Comment: Thanks for the attempted edit. It didn't work because I was already editing the answer to include the plot (which took longer than it ought for me to get right), but I had noticed the problem already.